# Где, собственно, приложение?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, приложение

В справочнике Розенталя нашел такое предложение:

***Увы! Моя шкатулка, шашка с серебряной оправой, дагестанский кинжал, подарок приятеля, — всё исчезло***.

Плюс фото:

[image: окоаовиурвои]

Розенталь говорит, запятая перед тире закрывает обособленное приложение. Где, собственно, это приложение? Я вижу перечисление однородных членов, не более.

Comment: дагестанский кинжал (который) подарок приятеля - не мой. Розенталь видимо намекает, что если бы не было запятой, то подарок приятеля был бы в однородном ряду, а так выходит, что это приложение. Поэтому вы всё правильно подумали, но не соотнесли мысли с лишней запятой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Где, собственно, приложение?

После слова ***кинжал***:

*Увы! Моя шкатулка, шашка с серебряной оправой, дагестанский кинжал, **подарок приятеля**, — всё исчезло*.

Comment: А-а-а, я думал, это однородные члены просто. Спасибо!